# How do you delete a row from a DataGrid in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagrid

I have an app for a Windows CE 6.5 mobile device. I am using Visual Studio 2008, coding in C# Windows Forms in a Smart Device Project. I have used a datagrid (not datagridview as these are not available). I am trying to delete the selected row but I cannot figure it out.

I have researched it but everything comes back with deleting from datagridview where you can use .selectedrow .  Can anyone point me in the right driection as to how to do this?

Attached is a photo to show that selectedrow isnt an option

[image: Options]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`CurrencyManager`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.currencymanager?view=netframework-4.8&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) class for this purpose like this:

```
var manager = (CurrencyManager)this.BindingContext[dataGrid1.DataSource];
var currentIndex = manager.Position;
manager.RemoveAt(currentIndex);
manager.Refresh();
```